# What string format is used to pass args in assert message in Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit

How can I create a string in Nunit and pass parameters to the error message

All (or almost all) Nunit asserts have a version that allows giving an error message with parameters.

For [instance](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.Null.html):

```
Assert.Null(object anObject);
Assert.Null(object anObject, string message, params object[] params);
```

What format do I need to use the message in, in order to use the params?

I've searched the documentation but it does not seem to show.

Answer (score 2):

Misformatting the string, gives an exception that shows that internally this uses the [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) Method from .Net

Meaning you can use `{0}`, `{1}`, etc to place arguments, with a lot of extra formatting options.

For example (not a very realistic case):

```
Assert.Equals(varExpectedValue, varActualValue, "Expected and actual value are false on iteration {0}", i);
```